# What's the meaning of "冒頭の言葉"?

Tags: meaning

I was trying to read a novel when I encountered this phrase:

> 出た感想が冒頭の言葉だ。

I can't seem to understand it. The only thing I found out was that 冒頭 meant beginning, but it doesn't seem to make sense if I directly substitute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

冒頭 means "beginning" so it is making a reference to whatever is written at the start of the text.
If it makes sense or not, it depends on the context.

Comment: I would like to add that, as described separately in [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/202330/meaning/m1u/%E5%86%92%E9%A0%AD/), the word 冒頭 is often used especially for beginning of a text, including novels.